# Web Browser control click

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I am using Web Browser control in my project and i open a web that have file chooser object.
Now i want to inject programmatically a path to a file in this file chooser object .

I tried to get the `HtmlElement` ,but i not found in the source code the element Id.

## Edit:

In the web there is "Browse..." button that open a file chooser,and then the file path is show in little text filed, and i want to inject the file path my self to the text field.

Comment: What is the actual goal?, - or, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the app will be able to choose programmatically the file that will be choosen and then upload it,instead of choose file and than upload it(because i want to do multiple uploads,file after file)

Comment: Why don't you use WebClient (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).? You can upload files (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx) and set the request headers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) as browsers do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. 
establish a name, id or class for the element you want to change the value of. There are a number of ways of doing this. I would use firebug for firefox, or IE developer toolbar, or just view the source of the page and establish what the name/Id of the  field is. Now if that field does not have a Name or an ID that you can use you might be able to get the containing element and iterate through the Child elements n times until you get the element you want.

For my embedded browser app I did the following in c#:-

```
// webBrowser is the name of the embedded IE browser in your app
var htmlDocument = webBrowser.Document;
if(htmlDocment!=null)
{
    var field = htmlDocument.GetElementById("...the id...");
    if(field!=null)
    {
        field.SetAttribute("value","...yourfilenamepathonyourmachine...");
    }

    // Now you would need to establish the ID of the submit element and click that
    var submitButton = htmlDocument.GetElementById("...submit button...");
    if(submitButton!=null)
    {
        submitButton.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
   // your code to loop?
}
```

So do you have the HTML of the page in question? that might help and a better answer can be given

Regards Julian

Comment: i tried to use it but i can't found the id of this elements in the source html

Comment: This method won't work, the value property is read only for a file input, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535126(v=VS.85).aspx.

Comment: sheng jiang...Interesting that you should say this will not work, this was production code and worked fine thanks